# How to view Linux file system through file browser dialog?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to allow the user to select a folder path in a Linux file system from my Windows forms application. There are a number of Linux machines on my network, but I'm not sure how to go about accessing them from Windows. A file browser dialog for the file system of each Linux machine is ideal, but I'm not sure if it is realistic. Is this possible?

I have not worked with Linux before so I am a bit over my head right now, any help / workarounds are appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: The easiest thing would be to map a network drive to the Linux machines (NFS mount, Samba, whatever).  Then the standard file dialog will see them just like any other Windows file system.

Comment: Can you see them in Windows Explorer? If not, you can't see them through the file browser dialog. If you can, then just opening  the file browser dialog will allow you to view the file system on the Linux box.

Comment: So I need to do ftp, samba, sftp, or nfs. Do you have any recommendations? No, I do not have them mapped to a network drive. It seems like that is the thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be done by mounting your linux systems onto your windows PC as network drives. See how to do this [here](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-network-drive-windows-10) (guide is for windows 10 but same principal applies.)

After doing so you should be able to see and navigate the drives using a standard `OpenFileDialog`. If you need more help just leave a comment and I can try help with what you cannot understand, but try google or search stackoverflow first and someone may already have the same problem as what you are facing.

Comment: @shasha Do you know how to set the `InitialDirectory` for an `OpenFileDialog` in a Windows Form Application that is running on Linux (through Mono). The file browser works but it doesn't seem to accept any initial directory using either `\` or `/`.

Comment: @Danny I haven't done WinForms in about 3 years, so I'm not sure.